# OSPF Aggregation and advertisement

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, ospf

In My Cisco Router i configured the following OSPF interfaces:

```
   interface eth1/0
      description link to net0 10.19.0.0/24 area 0 
      ip address 10.19.0.1 255.255.255.0
      ip ospf authentication message-digest
      ip ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 appropriate-password
      ip ospf cost 5000

interface eth1/1
      description link to p2p2 10.19.1.192/30 area 1 
      ip address 10.19.1.193 255.255.255.252
      ip ospf authentication message-digest
      ip ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 appropriate-password
      ip ospf cost 5000

    interface eth1/2
      description link to net3 10.19.2.0/24 area 0 
      ip address 10.19.2.1 255.255.255.0
      ip helper-address 10.19.0.20
      ip ospf authentication message-digest
      ip ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 appropriate-password
      ip ospf cost 5000
```

Then i have added the following interfaces

```
interface eth1/3
  description link to newnet4 10.19.16.0/23 area 2
  ip address 10.19.16.1 255.255.254.0
      ip helper-address 10.19.0.20
  ip ospf authentication message-digest
      ip ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 appropriate-password
  ip ospf cost 5000

interface eth1/4
  description link to newnet5 10.19.18.0/23 area 2
  ip address 10.19.18.1 255.255.254.0
      ip helper-address 10.19.0.20
  ip ospf authentication message-digest
      ip ospf message-digest-key 1 md5 appropriate-password
  ip ospf cost 5000
```

**i want to put eth1/3 and eth1/4 into area 2 and aggregate area 2's announcement to the core to only advertise an appropriate /22 for the two interfaces.**

I Have configured it as follow, but i coulden't get the expected behavior:

```
router ospf 1
    router-id 10.19.1.193
    log-adjacency-changes 

    network 10.19.1.0  0.0.0.255 area 0
    network 10.19.1.192  0.0.0.3  area 1
    network 10.19.2.0  0.0.0.255  area 0

    network 10.19.16.0  0.0.1.255 area 2
    network 10.19.18.0  0.0.1.255 area 2

    area 2   range 10.19.16.0  0.0.3.255
```

**Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with my config ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with my config

Simple. You used *wildcards* instead of *netmasks*. Also, you didn't enable authentication in the routing process.

[Cisco Reference: [OSPF Design Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/open-shortest-path-first-ospf/7039-1.html#t28)]

Comment: thank you but could you please be more specific and write me the correct config so i can understand it right ?

Comment: `0.0.0.255` is a wildcard. `255.255.255.0` is a netmask. Given the tech with which you are now playing, *you should know the difference.*

Comment: i know but, i want to know where is the error, as far as i understood it's in the area command